# C# Lambda syntax ToListAsync in VSCode

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax

angular 11 - I always mention VSCode since it has so many bugs.
however:

```
var roles = await _context.Roles.ToListAsync<AppRole>(x => { x.Id == Id } );
```

gets a

> "; expected csharp(CS1002)" and the column and squiggle point to the right `}` after Id.

I've tried a variety of changes and can't see what's wrong.  It should be selecting all AppRole records from the Roles Table that have the required "Id".

Any thoughts? Or am I just tired after a long week.
Thanks,
Yogi

Comment: Is that supposed to be a predicate?  Use `Where` before `ToListAsync`.

Comment: Yeah, it just might be that you're tired. It happens. You have a block-bodied lambda with a boolean expression, which doesn't qualify as a statement. If you put `;` after `Id` as it's telling you to do, you would get an error that "Only assignment, call, [...] can be used as a statement." Instead, if you remove `{` and `}`, you'd get an error like "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'CancellationToken' [...]". Athanasios has provided a correction, but I hope this comment has helped you understand the error better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var roles = await _context.Roles.Where(x =>  x.Id == Id ).ToListAsync();
```

The `ToListAsync` takes no predicate as parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0. To filter a dbset, you need to query with where and then cast `toList`

Up to the point of casting the queryable to list, no queries are executed.

You can chain the where function after the to list statement but that will bring everything into memory and the filter the list itself so it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.  I am studying the link you sent as well. :-)